# Firestore timestamp date range query with order by generate an error

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I wrote a query to filter some data based on the date range and want to order the result by some field (Int). The code I wrote generate "FIRInvalidArgumentException" exception.

If I removed the "order by" then the query execute perfectly. I have already created the index for **visitDate** and **views** fields.

*Index*: **visitDate Ascending views Descending**

```
let calendar = Calendar.current

let currentDateComponents = DateComponents(
  calendar: calendar,
  year: calendar.component(.year, from: Date()),
  month: calendar.component(.month, from: Date()),
  day: calendar.component(.day, from: Date()),
  hour: 0,
  minute: 0)

guard let currentDate = calendar.date(from: currentDateComponents) else {
  print("error");
  return
}

guard let weekEndDate = calendar.date(byAdding: .day, value: -7, to: currentDate) else {
  print("error");
  return
}

let queryRef = Firestore.firestore().collection("ArticleVisits")
  .whereField("visitDate", isGreaterThanOrEqualTo: weekEndDate)
  .whereField("visitDate", isLessThanOrEqualTo: currentDate)
  .order(by: "views", descending: true)
  .limit(to: limit)
```

Is there any issue using order by with date range? Do I need to create a special index for this?

Appreciate all the help.

Comment: Please include the exact, complete error message and stack trace in your question, as it typically contains important information about the cause of the problem.

Comment: That's not a valid Firestore query. You have to orderBy the same field you used for the range. [Order and Limit Data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/order-limit-data). Bottom example *you cannot perform Range filter and first orderBy on different fields*. Best bet here is to remove the order by and just sort in in code once the data is loaded.

Answer (score 1):

@Jay thanks for point me to right direction. According to the documentation it says,

> However, if you have a filter with a range comparison (<, <=, >, >=), your first ordering must be on the same field:

So I have to order it by **visitDate** instead of **views**.